# Ignore or handle an error when running a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I execute the batch of insert queries via SQL Server Mgmt Studio, it produces the following error but completes the insertion process of other queries.

> Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure X, Line 14
>   Error 50001, severity -1, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
>
> Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Y, Line 14
>   Error 50001, severity -1, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
>
> Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Z, Line 14
>   Error 50001, severity -1, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

But, while executing via ant job in terminal the insertion queries, the process halts with the below error message.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\test\mssql\build.xml:27: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\test\mssql\build-core.xml:74: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error 50001, 
severity -1, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, 
make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
```

I tried to handle the error by ignoring it:

```
set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

And by defining the try-catch block for the procedures throwing the error:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    RAISERROR (50001,-1,1, 'X');
    RAISERROR (50001,-1,1, 'Y');
    RAISERROR (50001,-1,1, 'Z');
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
               @ErrorState -- State.  
               );  
END CATCH;
```

But the error still persists in terminal with build failure.

If I define the custom error message as below:

```
EXEC sp_addmessage 50001, 16, N'Test Message'; 
GO
```

I just received the above error message in place of `but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.`

[image]

What could be the way such that the procedure throwing error gets handled and insertion continues further till the end like that of SQL client.

[image]

Comment: Trying to `CATCH` an error that you are manually raising seems..superfluous.   Why are you raising an error if you don't want to raise it?

Comment: RAISERROR can either reference a user-defined message stored in the sys.messages catalog view or build a message dynamically. If you look into the first code block there exists error, my understanding is I tried to define the existing error and catch them. May be I am wrong, but need to handle the error in the first code block.

Comment: I am unclear on what your actual problem is. Do you want to ignore generated errors and continue with a statement? If so, you'll have to catch the exception *on the client side*. That's the code that decides the first error produced by the T-SQL batch should generate an exception that prevents things from continuing. You cannot catch the error on the T-SQL side and resume the batch, because it has no features for that. You'd need to supply every individual statement with its own `TRY .. CATCH`. Note that `ANSI_WARNINGS` has no effect at all on this, `XACT_ABORT` does.

Comment: Wellll, maybe good old `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` could work, but it's unclear to me what Subash is really trying to do

Comment: @SubashBasnet when I look into the first code block, the only reason I see for an error is that you have 3 RAISERROR statements.  I don't understand why you want to ignore an error that you are raising, when you could just not-raise it in the first place.   I suspect that maybe the sample code you are providing isn't really helpful in illustrating what you're actually trying to do in your real code.

Comment: @TabAlleman: I had to double check that T-SQL doesn't have `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`. It has weirder stuff than that, after all. The effect you get with `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` is almost the same, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert omg, I could have SWORN I used to use `On Error Resume Next` in SQL Server 2000.   But you're right.   I must be remembering VBScript instead.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Yes, it's classic VB/VBScript. In T-SQL, you don't need it because it's practically what you get anyway -- [most errors don't abort the batch](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) even if you wanted them to. (Except with `XACT_ABORT ON`.)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking some more about what you must be trying to ask, I think the answer to your question is this:

You need to put EACH statement that might cause an error that you would want to ignore in its own TRY..CATCH block.   In each catch block, you can decide based on the error message whether you want to THROW it and stop processing, or do nothing but maybe store it in a variable, and continue.

Then at the end of everything you can check your variable(s) to see if there were any errors that you ignored and THROW them at that time (if you even want to), without rolling back the statements that have already run successfully.

Comment: Thanks! Just surrounding the whole batch of queries in the try-catch block solved the issue. Didn't require individual try-catch. E.g.:
`BEGIN TRY 
insert into x()values(); insert into y()values();
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
END CATCH;`